# Appending a string during list comprehension with np.arange()

Tags: python, string, numpy

I would a list like this example: `[1970s, 1980s, 1990, 2000s, 2010s]`.

```
list = [year for year in np.arange(1970, 2020, 10)]
```

creates a list without the `"s"` letter.

Is there a way to add a string during list generation? I tried `"+ "s""`, .append and similar but nothing worked.

I just need a list to be used as bin_labels. The comments solved the issues. Thanks.

Comment: `[f"{year}s" for year in np.arange(1970, 2020, 10)]`? this gives a list of strings.

Comment: To be picky, `np.arange` creates an array.  `range(1970,2020,10)` is prefered when iterating like this.

Comment: Other alternative: `np.char.array(np.arange(1970, 2020, 10)) + "s"`

Comment: Do you want to create a numpy array of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the format() function:

```
base = "{}s"
[base.format(year) for year in np.arange(1970, 2020, 10)]
```

Comment: Is this preferable to Ch3steR’s suggestion in the answers comment section?

Comment: They are equivalent. Choosing between the two is just a matter of code readability.

Comment: And f-strings are available from python3.6. Any python version below 3.6 you'd have use format.